# How to uninstall applications that were installed using tar command

Tags: software-installation, tar

Can anyone explain me how to uninstall the applications that are installed by extracting using `tar` command (`tar` files) .

I am really struggling to find an uninstall file . Surprisingly, I dont't find make file , (make related files) .

When I extract the `tar` file directly a binary file and its related files are distributed in my Linux PC .

Answer (score 8):

@JosephR. is on the right track. But don't use recursive `rm` - you'll find that the smallest bug suddenly removes your entire home directory (or worse). And to be extra safe, you might want to ensure that all the files exist *before* removing any of them. Untested code along these lines:

```
$ cat deletar.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset

tar tf "$1" | while read -r path
do
    if ! [ -e "$path" ]
    then
        echo "$0: Path does not exist: $path" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

tar tf "$1" | grep -v '/$' | xargs rm -f

tar tf "$1" | grep '/$' | xargs rmdir
```

Comment: Why is a recursive `rm` not preferred?

Comment: @JosephR.  Such tar files often include the root directory of where things get installed, such as `usr/local`.  The recursive `rm -rf` would then blow away *all* of `/usr/local`.